# Finding the Riemann curvature tensor with sympy.diffgeom for a sphere

Tags: python, sympy

I am testing the sympy.diffgeom library. My intention is to find the Riemann curvature tensor for a pre-calculated metric found from the transformation between cartesian and spherical coordinates. Here is the code

```
from sympy.diffgeom import Manifold, Patch, CoordSystem, TensorProduct
import sympy as sym
from sympy import cos,sinh,cosh, sin

m = Manifold("M",3)
patch = Patch("P",m)

cartesian = CoordSystem("cartesian",patch, ["x", "y", "z"])
x, y, z = cartesian.coord_functions()
spherical = CoordSystem("spherical", patch, ["r", "theta", "phi"])
r, theta, phi = spherical.coord_functions()
g = sym.Matrix([[1, 0, 0], [0, r**2, 0], [0, 0, r**2*sin(theta)**2]])

diff_forms = toroidal.base_oneforms()
metric_diff_form = sum([TensorProduct(di, dj)*g[i, j] for i, di in enumerate(diff_forms) for j, dj in enumerate(diff_forms)])

# Find the Riemann curvature tensor
from sympy.diffgeom import metric_to_Riemann_components
R = metric_to_Riemann_components(metric_diff_form)
```

When I run this, I get the following error for the last line

```
ValueError: The input expression concerns more than one coordinate systems, hence there is no unambiguous way to choose a coordinate system for the matrix.
```

I do not understand why, as I have tested the code for a different (more complex) metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix *g* is made up with the coordinate functions of the coordinate system *spherical*, you are mixing them with the two-forms of the coordinate system *toroidal*.

Try this, before transforming the metric matrix into a sum of two-forms:

```
diff_forms = spherical.base_oneforms()
```

The error message is quite straightforward.

Comment: I corrected that now, thanks. However, the result I end up is wrong though. For some reason, after simplifying the expression, I get `[[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],
 [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],
 [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]]`

Comment: I should be getting `r**2*sin(theta)**2` for the components `R[1][0][0][1] = -R[1][0][1][0]`, etc.

Comment: All components of R are zeros. The last version of SymPy has a bug, by which expressions of BaseScalarField don't get simplified. If you use the master development version, this bug has been fixed (by me some months ago), and the Riemann tensor has all components zero.

Comment: It makes sense, since the spherical coordinates represent a flat metric, so the Riemann tensor has to vanish, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right! I found some calculations on the following website : http://www.physicspages.com/2014/04/27/riemann-tensor-for-3-d-spherical-coordinates/ I need to some how verify that the output is correct. I will try to find a metric which does not give trivial results.

Comment: Try some negative components in the metric. As far as I know, if the metric signature is all positive, the space will be euclidean.